# Access elements on extlib Application Layout

Tags: search, xpages

I want to access the search options pulldown on the Application Layout control in order to check the value before selecting the page name.  I've tried

```
getComponent("searchopt").getValue()
```

but just get a null return.  I can't see anything obvious.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search bar doesn't have an id, so you can't use getComponent on it directly. You can get the Layout control using getComponent and you need to take it from there. The debug control can show how exactly the property names are.

Answer (score 1):

this should get a handle on the search Options as java.util.List of com.ibm.xsp.extlib.tree.ITreeNode objects
assuming you named your applicationLayout oneUILayout

```
var layout = getComponent( 'oneUILayout' );
var config = layout.getConfiguration();
var searchBar = config.getSearchBar();
var searchOptions = searchBar.getOptions();
```